# Calculator input and output fieldset

Tags: javascript, css, calculator

Halo

I have build a Calculator with (CSS, HTML, JavaScript).
the problem is that I can't manage to display the buttons on the (Form.input),
and the answers in to the (Form.Output)
The javascript code should work, but it doesn't do anything.
Any suggestions how to fix this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.keys button').on('click', function() {
        var value = $(this).value();
        $('.display.input').append(value);
    });

    $('button[name="="]').on('click', function() {

    });

    });
```

```css
/* reset */
*  {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    font-size: 5vw;
}

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


/* document */
body {
    font-family: "URW Gothic L", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
    /* Background source:
     * http://www.texturex.com/Leather-Textures/black+leather+texture+large+close+up+grain+material+dark+fabric+stock+photo.jpg.php
     * Free offered by Free Leather Textures */
    background: url('../../../media/black-leather-texture.jpg');
}

.display {
    border: 0.2rem solid gray;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    background: black;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
.display > output {
    display: block;
    height: 1.5rem;
    margin: 0;
    color: aqua;
}

form {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}

fieldset {
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}
fieldset > button {
    width: 20%;
    margin: 3.3%;
    padding: 2vw;
}
fieldset > button:nth-child(4n) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
fieldset > button:nth-child(4n+1) {
    margin-left: 0;
}

button {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.5rem black;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
output {
    font-size: 1rem;
}


button.number, button.command {
    background: white;
}
button.number:active, button.command:active {
    background: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0.5rem black;
}
button.operator {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.5rem rgb(80,80, 80);
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
button.operator:active {
    background: rgb(60, 60, 60);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0.5rem black;
}

#key-c {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
#key-c:active {
    background: darkred;
}
button:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.5rem deepskyblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Casio Mini</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />
        <script src="scripts/calculator.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <fieldset class="display">
                <output name="output" id="output" class="output"></output>
                <output name="input" id="input" class="input"></output>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <button type="button" name="key-0" id="key-0" class="number" value="0">0</button>
                <button type="button" name="key-1" id="key-1" class="number" value="1">1</button>
                <button type="button" name="key-2" id="key-2" class="number" value="2">2</button>
                <button type="button" name="key-+" id="key-+" value="+" class="operator">&plus;</button>

                <button type="button" name="key-3" id="key-3" class="number" value="3">3</button>
                <button type="button" name="key-4" id="key-4" class="number" value="4">4</button>
                <button type="button" name="key-5" id="key-5" class="number" value="5">5</button>
                <button type="button" name="key--" id="key--" value="-" class="operator">&minus;</button>

                <button type="button" name="key-6" id="key-6" class="number" value="6">6</button>
                <button type="button" name="key-7" id="key-7" class="number" value="7">7</button>
                <button type="button" name="key-8" id="key-8" class="number" value="8">8</button>
                <button type="button" name="key-*" id="key-*" value="*" class="operator">&lowast;</button>

                <button type="button" name="key-9" id="key-9" class="number" value="9">9</button>
                <button type="button" name="key-c" id="key-c" class="command">C</button>
                <button type="button" name="key-=" id="key-=" class="command">&equals;</button>
                <button type="button" name="key-/" id="key-/" value="/" class="operator">&divide;</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please make an executable example from your code, using a tool like jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

There were few issues in your code.

Here a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/871tvdrc/4/

Actually `.value()` doesn't exist in jQuery, it is `.val()`;

Then your selectors were wrong.

Here the right JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.keys button').on('click', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    console.log(value);
    $('.display .input').append(value);
  });

  $('button[name="="]').on('click', function() {

  });

});
```

Here the right HTML:

```
<form>
  <fieldset class="display">
    <output name="output" id="output" class="output"></output>
    <output name="input" id="input" class="input"></output>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="keys">
    <button type="button" name="key-0" id="key-0" class="number" value="0">0</button>
    <button type="button" name="key-1" id="key-1" class="number" value="1">1</button>
    <button type="button" name="key-2" id="key-2" class="number" value="2">2</button>
    <button type="button" name="key-+" id="key-+" value="+" class="operator">&plus;</button>

    <button type="button" name="key-3" id="key-3" class="number" value="3">3</button>
    <button type="button" name="key-4" id="key-4" class="number" value="4">4</button>
    <button type="button" name="key-5" id="key-5" class="number" value="5">5</button>
    <button type="button" name="key--" id="key--" value="-" class="operator">&minus;</button>

    <button type="button" name="key-6" id="key-6" class="number" value="6">6</button>
    <button type="button" name="key-7" id="key-7" class="number" value="7">7</button>
    <button type="button" name="key-8" id="key-8" class="number" value="8">8</button>
    <button type="button" name="key-*" id="key-*" value="*" class="operator">&lowast;</button>

    <button type="button" name="key-9" id="key-9" class="number" value="9">9</button>
    <button type="button" name="key-c" id="key-c" class="command">C</button>
    <button type="button" name="key-=" id="key-=" class="command">&equals;</button>
    <button type="button" name="key-/" id="key-/" value="/" class="operator">&divide;</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank You for your fast response.

Comment: I did copy the JavaScript cod, and the HTML cod, but steel is not working. I have to say that They are each in separate files.1 for HTML, 1 for CSS and 1 For JS.
If using the output and input in only 1 fieldset then is ok, but I have to output and input , that is when nothing is happens.

Comment: Did you add the right classes to all the elements? 
Can you paste me the complete code you have?
The example you posted before it's working completely well doing the changes I posted you, so I can't understand your actual code now

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=OeN49RzLth,                                                I used your cod and my code

Comment: sorry about that, my bad

Comment: can you see my changes?
you missed the `<fieldset class="keys">`

Then inside your JS you missed a space:
`$('.display .input').append(value);`